# Change Month in name instead of number in DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I have a DatePickerDialog, which is showing everything correct and also selecting the correct value. But I want to set the Month name Ex. "Jan" instead of M01.

Please see the below Image:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mhWPCPkARY4I1dvYZ6RdrXueUhHvMa4b/view

See the code:

```
public void setDueDate() {
    if (mYear == 0) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, final int year,
                                      final int monthOfYear, final int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    String strDate = mYear + "-" + (mMonth + 1) + "-" + mDay;
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    try {
                        Date date = format.parse(strDate);
                        tvDueDate.setText(format.format(date));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    datePickerDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    datePickerDialog.setTitle("");
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: if you want to go with library than check this libs [datepicker library android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27)

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7368

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430140/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for the quick reply boy! But I think you're lil bit misunderstood. I just want to change "M01" to Jan , like that "M02" to Feb.

Comment: here is the [OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smtSn.png) using that answer

Comment: @NileshRathod Please post with a full code

Comment: @PoojaSingh as you want to do like without library and dont want to add in XML. Its hard to do dear.

Comment: @PratikButani My boy, listen..In that Image whatever I posted, that yellow color is separately added dialog box and put that calendar picker inside it? or Android itself provide this functionality?

Comment: Yes, its provide different styles. Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652903/1318946